# Pandas very slow when loading data from csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python/pandas, and encountering an issue I can't really make sense of. I have Twitter data in csv files which contain 1000 tweets each. When I read the files into a dataframe, all works fine (it just takes a lot of time to read the files):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

#folders/files with csv data
folders = glob.glob("/media/Data/TwitterFeed/*")
files = []
for i in folders:
    files.extend(glob.glob("{0}/*".format(i)))

dflist = []
for j in range(len(files)):
    print("Working on file {0} of {1}".format(str(j + 1), str(len(files))))
    try:
        dftemp1 = pd.read_csv(files[j], usecols=["source", "text", "timestamp_ms"])
        dflist.append(dftemp1)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR! {0}!".format(e))
        pass
df = pd.concat(dflist, ignore_index=True)
```

This dataframe, which contains around 6 million tweets, can be manipulated at a reasonable speed. However, if it is saved

```
df.to_csv("data.csv") #file size is 1.1 GB
```

and read in a new python session

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col = 0)
```

even the most simple operations, e.g. finding a string in a tweet (which works perfectly fine in the initial dataframe!), is extremely slow (1-2s per row). The problem seems to be particularly distinct when I loop through all rows. Is there any reason for this? Would it help dumping all data into a database and reading it from there?

Here is the df.info() of the initial file (stopped after 50 files):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 50084 entries, 0 to 50083
Data columns (total 3 columns):
source                   49987 non-null object
text                     49988 non-null object
timestamp_ms             49984 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
```

Reloaded file:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5738558 entries, 0 to 5738557
Data columns (total 3 columns):
source                   object
text                     object
timestamp_ms             object
dtypes: object(3)
```

Comment: Is there reason you don't just store the dfs in a list and then concat them all? Also this line is unnecessary: `dftemp2 = pd.concat([dftemp1["source"], dftemp1["text"], dftemp1["timestamp_ms"]], axis=1)` you can specify the columns of interest in the params to `read_csv`, `usecols`:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Comment: Can you show `df.info()` before and after writing/reading it to csv?

Comment: @joris added df.info()

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, changed the code. Aside from speeding up the concat process from 2 hours to 10 minutes, it also solved the problem with the loaded csv - it runs at normal speed now (for whatever reason) :)

Comment: @Fab would you like me to post an answer, I can't explain everything but concatenating repeatedly was always going to be slower than building a single list upfront first and then concatenating all at once

Comment: I'm pretty sure that repeated concatenations make a copy of both the source and target dataframes each time. This gets big and slow as the target gets big. Concatenating the single list seems to have some deep magic that makes it faster. I suspect it has to do with allocating memory so that there's fewer copies.

Comment: @EdChum you should make that an answer.

Comment: @EdChum No, I think I am good here :)